# Shot Detection with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, detection, openframeworks

Do you know any open source code for shot boundary detection using openCV or other libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't post more than one link but here is an overview.
no source included but description is good

- http://www.hindawi.com/journals/asp/2009/509438.html

Suggest you google search for "shot boundary detection" to find several pdfs with algorithms